# Is there any way to close the dialog opened with file.show()?

Tags: r

After using 'file.show()' to open/display a text file, the dialog window stays at desktop. Of course, I can click 'File -> Close' or click windows 'close' mark (X) to close the dialog. Is there any way that we can close the dialog with script?  These is no such function like 'file.close()' that we can use in R. Thanks in advance.